# Which of the following queries in LINQ for List is faster - Query with AND or subqueries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following query in LINQ against List<>

eg:

```
 List<Person> list = new List<Person>
 {
new person{ID=1,Name="john",salary=2500, state="A", Street="AA"},
new person{ID=2,Name="Sena",salary=1500, state="B", Street="AB"},
new person{ID=3,Name="Max",salary=5500, state="C", Street="AA"},
new person{ID=4,Name="Gen",salary=3500, state="A", Street="AB"}
 };
```

is this faster?

```
var result = list.Where(p => p.state =="A" && p.Street=="AA" && p.salary>1000);
```

or

```
var result = list.Where(p => p.state =="A" )
                 .Where(p => p.Street=="AA")
                 .Where(p => p.salary>1000);
```

or

```
 var result = list.Where(p => p.state =="A" && p.Street=="AA")
                  .Where(p => p.salary>1000);
```

Which is prefered way, although all queries returns the same results. When there are few results any query may work faster. What if List<> contains 10000 of elements. I am sure certainly it will make a difference. Which one is faster?

Comment: first one............

Comment: why so? any explanation please

Comment: Write a simple test program , and start testing... ?  (I do agree that you will still not know why 1 or the other is faster...)

Comment: The first one will be faster in theory, but in practice the difference is negligible.

Comment: Firstly, if you want to know whether one code snippet is faster than another, you simply have to test them. There's no reason or excuse to ask here what you can test for yourself. Secondly, if the actual question you want answered is why something is the way it is then that's the question you should ask in your question. Don't ask a different question and then ask something else in the comments.

Comment: Execute and measure them

Comment: You can use BenchmarkDotNet to measure yourself. It's easy to do: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

The third one seems fastest, see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVtShp)

One of the tests returned:

```
A: 7.675900
B: 0.157700
C: 0.002200
```

Below the code used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static string getState(int gs)
    {
        switch (gs)
        {
            case 1:
                return "A";
            case 2:
                return "B";
            default:
                return "C";
        }

        ;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>{new Person{ID = 1, Name = "john", salary = 2500, state = "A", Street = "AA"}, new Person{ID = 2, Name = "Sena", salary = 1500, state = "B", Street = "AB"}, new Person{ID = 3, Name = "Max", salary = 5500, state = "C", Street = "AA"}, new Person{ID = 4, Name = "Gen", salary = 3500, state = "A", Street = "AB"}};
        // add 10000 Persons
        for (int x = 5; x < 100000; x++)
        {
            list.Add(new Person()
            {ID = x, Name = x.ToString(), salary = rnd.Next(1500, 5500), state = getState(rnd.Next(1, 3)), Street = getState(rnd.Next(1, 3)) + getState(rnd.Next(1, 3))});
        }

        DateTime start;
        // A
        start = DateTime.Now;
        var resultA = list.Where(p => p.state == "A" && p.Street == "AA" && p.salary > 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("A: {0:N6}", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1.0);
        
        // B
        start = DateTime.Now;
        var resultB = list.Where(p => p.state == "A").Where(p => p.Street == "AA").Where(p => p.salary > 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("B: {0:N6}", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1.0);
        // C
        start = DateTime.Now;
        var resultC = list.Where(p => p.state == "A" && p.Street == "AA").Where(p => p.salary > 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("C: {0:N6}", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1.0);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int salary { get; set; }

    public string state { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: The last 6 results when testing using BenchmarkDotNet:

```
A: 0,001  B: 0,001  C: 0,0325
A: 0,0006  B: 0,001  C: 0,0329
A: 0,0007  B: 0,001  C: 0,0314
A: 0,0007  B: 0,001  C: 0,0312
A: 0,0007  B: 0,001  C: 0,0329
A: 0,0007  B: 0,001  C: 0,0313
```

Conclusion: testing is more difficult than most people believe ...

Comment: When applying BenchmarkDotNet (just to see if that changes anything) there is a shift towards "A".....